# Java How to convert List to Map with multiple arguments function

Tags: java

I want to convert List to Map using stream and collector. I've searched through many examples but I couldn't figure out how to convert following example:

```
private List<String> list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}

private static String repeatAlphabet(String alphabet, int repeatCount) {
    return StringUtils.repeat(alphabet, repeatCount);
}

void Map<String, String> foo(int repeatCount) {
    Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (String alphabet : list) {
        map.put(alphabet, repeatAlphabet(alphabet, repeatCount));
    }
    return map;
}
```

so the result should be like:

```
foo(3) = {
    "a": "aaa",
    "b": "bbb",
    "c": "ccc",
    "d": "ddd"
};
```

This is something I've tried:

```
void Map<String, String> foo(int repeatCount) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            a -> repeatAlphabet(a, repeatCount),
            Function.identity()));
}
```

but it shows an error:

```
Wrong first argument found: <lambda parameter>, required: Java.Lang.String
```

Comment: You need to search some more... map[alphabet] is not compiling.... map.put(key,value)  would... search "java map example"

Comment: @PetterFriberg Oops! I've edited it. That wasn't a point of the question though.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what `repeatAlphabet` returns. (i.e. what's the return type)

Comment: Side-note, `repeatAlphabet` can be written without any external dependency as `String.join("", Collections.nCopies(repeatCount, alphabet))`

Comment: @Eran I've edited it, thanks!

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for your side note

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, what you need to return is simply :

```
return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s->s,s->repeatAlphabet(s, repeatCount)));
```

This returns a `Map` whose key is an element of the `List` and the value is the repeated `String`.

P.S. I'm assuming `repeatAlphabet` should return a `String`. I guess it's a typo in your question (the return type is not specified).

Comment: It seems this example doesn't provide compilable code either T^T

Answer (score 0):

I still cant comment, so i have to use answer. @Eran answer is correct, 
maybe your problem is methods signature have two return type.
In question there is:

```
void Map<String, String> foo(int repeatCount)
```

but correct one is:

```
Map<String, String> foo(int repeatCount)
```